# How to specify an attribute namespace in XSD so that JAXB interprets it correctly?

Tags: java, xml, namespaces, jaxb, xsd

I have a small problem with attribute namespaces within an existing XSD. I have to modify this XSD in order to use all functionality of a third-party software.
My goal is to mix an element with a namespaced attribute, like this:

```
<graphics type="RECTANGLE" cy:nodeLabel="Label 1" />
```

The `<graphics>` element is defined in the default namespace, the attribute `cy:nodeLabel` in a specific namespace.

Currently, my attribute definition in the XSD looks like this:

```
<xsd:attribute name="nodeLabel" type="xsd:string" form="qualified" xmlns="http://www.cytoscape.org"/>
```

The option `form="qualified"` forces JAXB to annotate the `@XmlAttribute` with `namespace="...."`, but it takes the default namespace, instead of http://www.cytoscape.org. If I change this manually in the generated Java classes, the XML output is as desired.

I would like to define the attribute namespace within the XSD, so that I can rely on JAXB (resp. xjc) to generate the correct Java classes.
How can I specify an attribute namespace for one attribute in the XSD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single xsd file can only define a *single* namespace.  you need a *separate* xsd which defines the second namespace, which you would then import into the original xsd (and reference the attribute accordingly).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [jtahlborn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19224636/32043), I found the appropriate solution:

Import separate XSD:

New file `cytoscape-additions.xsd`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  targetNamespace="http://www.cytoscape.org" elementFormDefault="unqualified"
  attributeFormDefault="qualified">

  <!-- Cytoscape additions Graphics -->
  <xsd:attributeGroup name="cytoscape-addition-graphics">
    <xsd:attribute name="nodeLabel" type="xsd:string" form="qualified"
    xmlns="http://www.cytoscape.org" />
  </xsd:attributeGroup>
</xsd:schema>
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12111103/32043